# How to build a histogram?

Tags: java

I need help on building a histogram (in Java) that will take a list of numbers (an array) that range from 0 to 9 and output how many occurrences of each number exist. So for example, with `{1,5,3,4,5,5,5,4,3,2,5,5,5,}` it would print:

```
0 - 0
1 - 1
2 - 1
3 - 3
4 - 2
5 - 7
6 - 0
7 - 0
8 - 0
9 - 0
```

This is the code I have so far:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Histogram
{
   private int[] numCount;

   public Histogram(int[] array)
   {
      setArray(array);
   }

   public void setArray(int[] array)
   {
      numCount=array;
   }

   public String toString()
   {
      int count=0;
      String boi="";
      for(int x=0; x<=9; x++)
      {
        for (int y=0; y<numCount.length; y++)
        {
           if (numCount[x]==numCount[y])  
           count++;
           boi=x+" - "+ count+"\n";
        }
      }      
      return boi;
   }
```

}

When I run this (in a seperate runner file) it prints "9-40". Would greatly appreciate any help that can be offered. Thank you!

Comment: I think you meant `if (numCount[y] == x)`

Comment: You're appending to the boi string with each loop, but you won't know the final histogram tally until *all* the numbers have been looped through.

Comment: You probably also meant `boi += x+" - "+ count+"\n"`, to actually *append* to `boi`, and to do that outside the `y` loop, and to initialize `count=0` inside the `x` loop. That was 4 logic errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several errors in your code: First one is, you don't initialize `count` in the outer for-loop. In your code, `count` is set to `0` once and incremented for every number, but it's never reset.
Second one is the comparison `numCount[x] == numCount[y]`. This will check how often the value in the `numCount` array at position `x` is in the array. 
Then your String `boi` is created but you don't append the latest line to it, instead you overwrite it. So you will always see the last line (with `x = 9`)
Following method should work:

```
public String toString() {
    String boi="";
    for(int x=0; x <= 9; x++) {
        int count=0;
        for (int y=0; y < numCount.length; y++) {
            if (x == numCount[y]) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        boi = boi + x + " - " + count + "\n";
    }      
    return boi;
}
```

(You could also use `boi += x + " - " + count + "\n";` or a `StringBuilder` and its `append`-method)

Comment: Thank you so much! It works perfectly. Was struggling with this all weekend lol.